# mask add in jquery on key up

Tags: jquery, mask

I want to add mask on input(key up) to check the user's credit card number. I have created this script but it does not work perfectly.

```
function card_checker(cardinput) {
    var cardno_american = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;
    var cardno_visa = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;
    var cardno_master = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;
    var cardno_discover = /^(?:6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/;
    var cardno_dinner = /^(?:3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11})$/;
    var cardno_jcb = /^(?:(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/;
    if (cardinput.match(cardno_visa)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (cardinput.match(cardno_master)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (cardinput.match(cardno_discover)) {
        return 2;
    } else if (cardinput.match(cardno_american)) {
        return 3;
    } else if (cardinput.match(cardno_jcb)) {
        return 6;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
var oldVal;
$('#card_number').on('keypress paste textInput input', function() {
    var res = card_checker($('#card_number').val());
    var val = this.value;
    console.log(res);
    if ((val != oldVal) && (val.length == 1) && res == 3) {
        $(this).mask('9999-9999-9999-999', {
            "translation": {
                "#": null
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(this).mask('9999-9999-9999-9999', {
            "translation": {
                "#": null
            }
        });
    }
    oldVal = val;
    $(this).val(oldVal);
});
```

This does not work on american express card.

Comment: You might look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html, which has a regular expression for Amex that differs from yours.

Comment: Thanks Graham Asher I have read and found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Amex Card number ( no hyphens )

```
/^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/ // matches the first 2 digit which starts with either 37 or 34 and rest 13 digits
```

( With hyphens : xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx)

```
/^3[47]\d\d([\ \-]?)\d{6}\1\d{5}$/
```

Comment: I am facing problem in adding mask $(this).mask('9999-9999-9999-999')